# Attempt to concatenate global 'sceneName' (a nil value) - Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I actually copy and pasted this code and it worked for my friend.

This is the code for main.lua

```
composer = require( "composer" )

composer.gotoScene("mainMenu")
```

In the same directory i have a file named "mainMenu", this is the code:

```
local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:show(event)
  -------------
end


scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
return scene
```

As i run the app i get the error "Attempt to concatenate global 'sceneName' (a nil value)"

Comment: Please make it clear in your question this relates to the "corona" environment. LUA itself does not have scenes, or a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the scene template. Try to require composer to a local variable within your scene file.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/index.html#scene-template

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Code outside of the scene event functions below will only be executed ONCE unless
-- the scene is removed entirely (not recycled) via "composer.removeScene()"
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------




-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scene event functions
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- create()
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs when the scene is first created but has not yet appeared on screen

end


-- show()
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is entirely on screen

    end
end


-- hide()
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs immediately after the scene goes entirely off screen

    end
end


-- destroy()
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs prior to the removal of scene's view

end


-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scene event function listeners
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```